# Отправка данных с сайта в 1C

Tags: php, 1с

Подскажите пожалуйста, желательно на примерах, как я могу отправлять данные в 1С, просто раньше никогда с этим с 1С не работал, а тут пришлось всё-таки с ним связаться. На сайт надо подключить кнопку типа "Позвони мне", кнопку сделать смогу, скрипт написать тоже, только вообще представить даже не могу как отправлять всю эту информацию в 1С.

Comment: для чего инфо передается в 1С?

Comment: Вариант 1. Настраиваете Веб сервисы http://programmist1s.ru/web-servisyi-v-1s/ ; Вариант 2. Из своих скриптов вызываете 1С как COM-объект. Первый вариант предпочтительней

Comment: Как вариант: записывай в текстовый файл клади его в директорию; из 1С читай файл, ответ из 1С снова клади в текстовый файл; Вместо файла можно использовать формат .dbf .mdb .xls SQLLite

Answer (score 1):

Думаю для этого вам нужно использовать либо Web-сервис, либо HTTP-сервис. Они публикуются на стороне 1С. В них можно создать нужные методы и к ним обращаться.